# Java drawing- need to refresh screen

Tags: java, swing, jframe, draw, paint

In this code are two buttons.One makes rectangle move to the right on x axis, and second makes rectangle move down on y axis.My problem is, that each previous position of rectangle stays on screen and it looks like rect is leaving a trail behind it.Anny suggestions how could I clear screen or something?

```
public class testing extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
public JButton button;
public JButton button2;
public boolean check;
public int x;
public int y;

public void paint(Graphics g){
    if(check==true){
    g.setColor(Color.red);
    g.fillRect(x, y, 50, 50);
    }
}

public void start(){
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    button=new JButton();
    button2=new JButton();

    button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,50));
    button.setText("R"); 
    button.addActionListener(this);
    button2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,50));
    button2.setText("D");
    button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){y=y+10;check=true;repaint();}});

    add(button);
    add(button2);

    setSize(500,500);
    setVisible(true);       
}   

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    x=x+10;
    check=true;
    repaint();
}

public static void main(String args[]){
    testing x=new testing();
    x.start();
}
    }
```

Comment: "Swing programs should override `paintComponent()` instead of overriding `paint()`."—[*Painting in AWT and Swing: The Paint Methods*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html#callbacks).

Comment: 1) Don't extend frame or other top level containers.  Instead create & use an instance of one. 2) Instead of painting in a top level container such as `JFrame`, add a `JPanel` & do custom painting in the `paintComponent(Graphics)` method.  Also return a sensible preferred size for the custom component, to assist the layout manager. 3) Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow.

Comment: Hello Andrew Thompson :) Thank you for valuable informations, it's much appreciated.I try to write code so I can easily read it, it wasn't supposed to be public but I thought people would be able to read such a simple code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure on this, but I believe you need to call the parent's paint method, so change your paint method to this:

```
public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    super.paint(g);

    if(check)
    {
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fillRect(x, y, 50, 50);
    }
}
```